Is it possible to have ongoing 120K-6M non-blocking HTTP requests getting responses after seconds and minutes? What PC limitation may prevent it?
Context:
I am considering implementing a top level general backend calling various specialized backends via HTTP using non-blocking requests (using promises, futures etc.).
The responses to the calls/requests to other backends may take seconds and even minutes.
I understand every non-blocking request should put something like a promise or future into some queue of promises/futures of my top level general (non-specialized) backend.
The queue of promises/futures grows when the top level backend makes a request.
The queue gets shorter when a requests from the queue gets a response and the corresponding promise/future is used.
I cannot get one thing.
If my top level general backend makes, let's say, 2000 HTTP requests a second and some requests may take seconds (quite slow) and some minutes (really slow) to get responses and on average, let's assume, a request takes 1 minutes to get its response then it should mean the underlying language/technology/framework and hardware/RAM/disk/whatever should be able to keep/maintain/process a queue of 120K promises/futures.
Then if the rate is higher like 100K requests per second then there should be ability to maintain a queue of 6M promises/futures.
Something in me tells me that having 6M outstanding promises/futures at every single moment of runtime of my top level backend is wrong, unreliable and unlikely to be supported by various backend technologies like non-blocking Java frameworks/Node.js/other non-blocking frameworks in various programming languages or PC operating systems or hardware.
I can think of scaling out the top level backend (to multiple lesser uniform instances) to keep its promise/futures queue within the capabilities of the technologies/hardware chosen.
Yet I have a feeling that the very approach of long lasting requests/promises/futures is wrong and there should be something else I cannot remember or am not aware of.
I feel like making specialized backends responding immediately with 'acknowledge, working' and polling for results could be a better option yet it will delay the responses got faster by the time fraction of polling rate interval.
The question is not bound to any specific language, framework or technology. It is about limitations of operating systems, TCP, HTTP on contemporary PC machines.
The very question is: 
Is it possible to have ongoing 120K-6M non-blocking HTTP requests getting responses after seconds and minutes in one PC server instance? 
If no then what contemporary PC, TCP, HTTP, operating systems limitation does make it impossible?
Note: I am considering PC machines only.

You may consider the use of web hooks for example to avoid polling which may cause high loads on the specialized backends.

@SpaceTrucker, could you explain a bit how web hooks allow to avoid both polling and long queue of promises?
I do not understand the idea.

Use of web hooks was not specifically meant to get rid of the many promises but only the polling.

@SpaceTrucker, thank you!
I will study them then.
I understand that they should allow for feedback from the specialized backends on completion of their doings.
Please answer with your suggestion if you feel it is appropriate to the question.
At least it answers part of my question and I am going to use it.


maintain a queue of 6M promises/futures.

PC computers generally have 64K ports, thus a PC could not sustain 6M (port involved) promises at one time, I think.
But outside of the PC world, maybe there's specific hardware that does have the ports to support this.

Thank you for your answer!
Is it always one port / outgoing connection per promise / outgoing http request?

@AlexanderItes not per promise, but per network connection

Then it was exactly what I felt and could not remember (a limit I forgot about).
I think the answer covers the whole question exactly.

64K ports is a limitation in TCP/IP itself, however connections are defined by the combination of source IP+port and destination IP+port, so the maximum number of ports does not in itself define the maximum number of concurrent connections.

Perhaps using HTTP/2 can reduce the number of ports needed as well because the set of specialized backends is small and known.
